# Get notifications even if using Android Wear Application

Tags: notifications, android-notifications, wear-os, android

Is it possible to get notification in Android wear if wear specific application is running in Android wear device. I noticed that I got notified only after existing my wear application.

Another problem I faced is, If one reads a notification and if another notification comes, it just closed the current notification and opened the recent notification.

Is that the way Android wear actually works? or am I wrong somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question : you are notified, the device vibrates, but since your Wear application is in full screen and notifications are only displayed on the watch face, you can't see them/interact with them while you are on the application.

For the second one : it's the way the Card stream works, if you receive a notification while reading another, once you cancel the second one, the new notification will pop up, being at the top of your stream.